# Flutter: Setting BuildContext to null from another class

Tags: flutter, dart, pass-by-reference

I would like to know how to nullify a `BuildContext` from another class to prevent it from being used by an asynchronous function after context's widget has been disposed.

I assumed that it was passed by reference, so I tried setting it to `null` in the original widget (in my use case, I was setting it to `null` in the dispose method and the `onWillPop` method, both to no avail). I created a simple example app for what I would like to do. As you can see if you run the app, the context is not set to `null`.

```
import 'dart:async';

import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void main() => runApp(MyApp());

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      title: 'Setting BuildContext to null',
      theme: ThemeData(
        primarySwatch: Colors.blue,
      ),
      home: MyHomePage(title: 'Setting BuildContext to null'),
    );
  }
}

class MyHomePage extends StatefulWidget {
  MyHomePage({Key key, this.title}) : super(key: key);
  final String title;

  @override
  _MyHomePageState createState() => _MyHomePageState();
}

class _MyHomePageState extends State<MyHomePage> {
  AsyncClass _asyncClass = AsyncClass();
  Duration duration = const Duration(seconds: 5);
  void toggleContext(BuildContext context){
    Timer.periodic(duration, (_){
      print("Setting context to null");
      context = null;

    });
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    toggleContext(context);
    _asyncClass.asyncFunc(context);
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text(widget.title),
      ),
      body: Center(),
    );
  }
}

class AsyncClass{
  void asyncFunc(BuildContext context){
    const duration = const Duration(seconds: 1);
    Timer.periodic(duration, (_){
      if(context==null){
        print("Context is null");
      } else {
        print("Context is not null");
      }

    });
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found that I can use the `ValueParameter` class to wrap the `BuildContext` object. This allows me to very simply pass the new `ValueParameter` value into functions and set them all to `null` very easily from any function it's incorporated in.

Here's my solution (I added `if(_timer==null)` to prevent duplicate `Timer`s from forming when the application refreshes).

```
import 'dart:async';

import 'package:flutter/foundation.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void main() => runApp(MyApp());

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      title: 'Setting BuildContext to null',
      theme: ThemeData(
        primarySwatch: Colors.blue,
      ),
      home: MyHomePage(title: 'Setting BuildContext to null'),
    );
  }
}

class MyHomePage extends StatefulWidget {
  MyHomePage({Key key, this.title}) : super(key: key);
  final String title;

  @override
  _MyHomePageState createState() => _MyHomePageState();
}

class _MyHomePageState extends State<MyHomePage> {
  AsyncClass _asyncClass = AsyncClass();
  Duration duration = const Duration(seconds: 5);
  Timer _timer;
  void toggleContext(ValueNotifier context) {
    if (_timer == null)
      _timer = Timer.periodic(duration, (_) {
        print("Setting context to null");
        context.value = null;
      });
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext param) {
    ValueNotifier context = ValueNotifier(param);
    toggleContext(context);
    _asyncClass.asyncFunc(context);
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text(widget.title),
      ),
      body: Center(),
    );
  }
}

class AsyncClass {
  Timer _timer;
  void asyncFunc(ValueNotifier context) {
    const duration = const Duration(seconds: 1);
    if (_timer == null)
      _timer = Timer.periodic(duration, (_) {
        if (context.value == null) {
          print("Context is null");
        } else {
          print("Context is not null");
        }
      });
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

`context` in `asyncFunc` is simply a copy of the reference to the original `BuildContext` object on the Dart heap, so setting `context` to null will only set that particular variable to null, not all variables that have the same reference.

If you're from a C/C++ background, what you're doing is more akin to changing the address value of a pointer rather than changing the value that lives at the address a pointer points to.

**EDIT:** A potential solution is to do something like this:

```dart
class AsyncClass{
  BuildContext context;
  void asyncFunc(BuildContext param){
    context = param;
    const duration = const Duration(seconds: 1);
    Timer.periodic(duration, (_){
      if(context==null){
        print("Context is null");
      } else {
        print("Context is not null");
      }
    });
  }
}
```

and then do this:

```dart
  void toggleContext(BuildContext context){
    Timer.periodic(duration, (_){
      print("Setting context to null");
      _asyncClass.context = null;
    });
  }
```

Comment: I know in C++ that I would be able to dereference the pointer. I wonder if there's any way to do that in this case.

Comment: Not exactly, no. However, you can do something like I've just added to the original answer.

Comment: Thank you, I think I found an even simpler solution -- to use `ValueNotifier` to wrap the `BuildContext`

Comment: Ah yes, of course. I totally forgot about `ValueNotifier`. Glad you found a solution!

Comment: getting this error when i show dialog in api success nethod.Failed assertion: line 446 pos 12: 'context != null': is not true.